# Why private members get inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-modifiers

So `private` members in the base class are also in the inherited class but not accessible in it, right?
Are they actually in the memory allocated to the the inherited object?

Comment: inheritance is a `is-a` relationship, so yes, all the memory the base class requires is required in the sub-class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are they actually in the memory allocated to the the inherited object?

Yes, they need to exist.  The private members are part of the implementation detail of the base class.  Without them, in general, the base class wouldn't be able to function (which is why they exist in the first place).

Making them private just allows the base class to create its implementation however it chooses, without exposing that to anybody, including the subclass.

Comment: In addition to this good answer, I'd say that basically when you have a base class MyBase for example, and it is inherited by some class MyDerived(no matter how - public, private or protected), and when you create a object of type MyDerived, in the object layout in memory, you'll have an object of type MyBase inside actually. So simply said: every object of type MyDerived will have an object of type MyBase inside it.

Comment: @BlackCat - Re *So simply said: every object of type MyDerived will have an object of type MyBase inside it.* Diamond inheritance. Suppose B and C each inherit virtually from A, D inherit from B and C. At least one of the B and C objects embedded inside an instance of class D will not contain an A object "inside" them.

Comment: @David: both of B and C will have a pointer to a common (shared) base class A object. And while they do not necessarily have object of class A inside they behave like they had.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Just for example, you can use a public function from the base class that manipulates private data, even in an instance of the derived class:

```
class Base { 
    int x;
public:
    Base() : x(0) {}
    void inc() { ++x; }
    void show() { std::cout << x << "\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base { 
};

int main() { 
    Derived d;
    d.show();
    d.inc();
    d.show();
}
```

With a properly functioning compiler, this must display:

```
0
1
```

...showing that the data in the Base object is present in the Derived object, even though it's not (directly) accessible.

Of course with almost anything in C++, there's the "as-if" rule -- if the compiler can determine that it can somehow produce the correct observable behavior for the program, even without including the private part(s) of the base class, then it's free to do so. The most obvious example of this would be if you included something (member function or data) in the base class that was simply never used in practice.

Comment: what if you compile into a distributable DLL, how can you ever know if a specific member function does not get used?

Comment: @TemplateRex: Chances are that it can't, so under those circumstances, it most likely has no possibility of omitting it.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem of a once-derived class is that it can be inherited from again, and the potential children are an open set. So unless `Derived` is marked as `final`, I don't think the compiler can ever apply the as-if rule to its class-layout. On top of that, the set of future callers is also an open set.

Comment: @TemplateRex: The compiler (per se) may not be able to -- but the linker often can/will.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are,

When object of the derived class is being constructed all of its base classes are first being constructed as well.

Consider this example:

```
class Base
{
 int x;

 public:
  Base(int px)
   : x(px)
  {
  }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 int y;
public:
  Derived(int px, int py)
   : y(py), Base(px)
  {
  }
};
```

This example compiles and works and Base is initialized (constructor is called) before you reach the body of the Derived constructor.